# How to use environment variables in SASS?

Tags: sass

How to use environment variables in SASS?

I have these SASS files inside my Framework:

```
Variables.scss
General.scss
Layout.scss
List.scss
Form.scss
Table.scss
All.scss
```

And inside `All.scss`, I've just included other files:

```
@import 'Variables';
@import 'General';
@import 'Layout'
@import 'List'
@import 'Form'
@import 'Table'
```

This exists in the Framework. In other projects A, B, and C, I want to be able to use this, and also override them if necessary. So, in project C for example, I have:

```
Variables.scss
List.scss
Form.scss
All.scss
```

As you see, only lists and forms need to be a little different, via colours and paddings and margins defined in `Variables.scss`.

The is how projects are on my physical disk:

```
D:\Company\Framework\WebUi\Styles\
D:\Company\ProjectA\Web\
D:\Company\ProjectB\Web\
D:\Company\ProjectC\Web\
...
```

Now I want to be able to reuse `SASS` files from Framework. Since these paths are only consistent across developers' machines from `Company` folder onwards, We have created an Environment Variable:

```
CompanyProjectsRoot => D:\Company
```

Now, I need to write something like this in `All.scss` of project C:

```
@import '%CompanyProjectsRoot\Framework\WebUi\Styles\All.scss';
@import 'Variables'
@import 'List'
@import 'Form'
```

But it doesn't work. Can I use Environment Variables in SASS files?

Comment: No. But you can read it from your task runner. What built tool are you using? gulp, grunt?